# Get image thumbnail from google drive in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Is it possible to get image thumbnail from google drive image file ?  When I'm opening the native google drive app, it shows me thumbnails of images, but when I'm opening the file chooser of API, it's shows me default icon for all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive Android API doesn't provide thumbnails at the moment, they will be likely to be available on the new version.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, actually.

On the file (`com.google.api.services.drive.model.File`) you get back, just call `getThumbnailLink()`. That will be the thumbnail of the image. However, if it's not an image, if I remember correctly, it will simply be blank (not null, but just blank).

Comment: Thanks @kentarosu, but this is for old API. I need to get thumbnails from new API.

Comment: ...I'm not sure what you mean, this is currently what the RESTful Api uses. Did you mean that you are instead using the Google Drive SDK for Android?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Google Drive SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I had an error in the discussion of the request fields.

As far as I can tell, there is literally no good documentation on the solution for this. It's true that you can't get thumbnails with the Drive Android API, however you **can** get thumbnails with the Drive Java Client Library. This page has is a really good primer for getting started:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android

Oddly, I can't get the fields portion of the request to work as it is on that quick start. As I've experienced, you have to request the fields a little differently.

Since you're doing a custom field request you have to be sure to add the other fields you want as well. Here is how I've gotten it to work:

```
Drive.Files.List request = mService.files()
                    .list()
                    .setFields("files/thumbnailLink, files/name, files/mimeType, files/id")
                    .setQ("Your file param and/or mime query");

FileList files = request.execute();
files.getFiles();  //Each File in the collection will have a valid thumbnailLink
```

A sample query might be:

```
"mimeType = 'image/jpeg' or mimeType = 'video/mp4'"
```

Hope this helps!