# Handling of Thumbnails in Google Drive Android API (GDAA)

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I've run into the following problem when porting an app from [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) API to [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro).
The app needs to download some of (thousands of) JPEG images based on user selection. The way this is solved in the app is by downloading a thumbnail version first, using this construct of the REST API:

```
  private static InputStream getCont(String rsid, boolean bBig){
    InputStream is = null;
    if (rsid != null) try {
      File gFl = bBig ?
      mGOOSvc.files().get(rsid).setFields("downloadUrl"  ).execute():
      mGOOSvc.files().get(rsid).setFields("thumbnailLink").execute();
      if (gFl != null){
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(bBig ?  gFl.getDownloadUrl() : gFl.getThumbnailLink());
        is = mGOOSvc.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(url).execute().getContent();
      }
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException uraEx) {
      authorize(uraEx.getIntent());
    } catch (GoogleAuthIOException gauEx) {}
    catch (Exception e) { }
    return is;
  }
```

It allows to get either a 'thumbnail' or 'full-blown' version of an image based on the *bBig* flag. User can select a thumbnail from a list and the full-blown image download follows (all of this supported by disk-base LRU cache, of course).
The problem is, that GDAA does not have an option to ask for *reduced size / thumbnail* version of an object (AFAIK), so I have to resort to combining both APIs, which makes the code more convoluted [then I like (bottom of the page)](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth). Needles to state that the 'Resource ID' needed by the REST may not be immediately available.
So, the question is: Is there a way to ask GDAA for a 'thumbnail' version of a document?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an exposed way to retrieve thumbnails with the Android API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580570/get-image-thumbnail-from-google-drive-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading thumbnails isn't currently available in the Drive Android API, and unfortunately I can't give a timeframe to when it will be available. Until that time, the Drive Java Client Library is the best way to get thumbnails on Android.

We'd appreciate if you go ahead and file a feature request against our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/

That gives requests more visibility to our teams internally, and issues will be marked resolved when we release updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I had an error in the discussion of the request fields.

As Ofir says, you can't get thumbnails with the Drive Android API and you **can** get thumbnails with the Drive Java Client Library. This page has is a really good primer for getting started:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android

Oddly, I can't get the fields portion of the request to work as it is on that quick start. As I've experienced, you have to request the fields a little differently.

Since you're doing a custom field request you have to be sure to add the other fields you want as well. Here is how I've gotten it to work:

```
Drive.Files.List request = mService.files()
                    .list()
                    .setFields("files/thumbnailLink, files/name, files/mimeType, files/id")
                    .setQ("Your file param and/or mime query");

FileList files = request.execute();
files.getFiles();  //Each File in the collection will have a valid thumbnailLink
```

A sample query might be:

```
"mimeType = 'image/jpeg' or mimeType = 'video/mp4'"
```

Hope this helps!